# How to perform an action when a user slides up a push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I want to perform a action when a user slides up a push notification on home screen in iOS. Precisely which functions gets called when a user slides up a local push notification.

Comment: There is a function that gets called when your app is launched from a local notification. Not sure if that is what you're asking for.

Comment: Actually I have a VOIP application. What I want is when a user discards a local notification(slides it up) while app is running in Background, I want to call a web service

Comment: Apple doesn't provide any feedback if the user has seen the notification, or discarded. David's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think you cannot get that kind of event..